# TCPDF - how to add a font to pdf

Tags: fonts, tcpdf

While using TCPDF to generate pdf files I am trying to embed fonts to my pdf file. I have read about it in manuals and i've been googling for it for a few hours.

I used that method:

```
$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('/fonts/aller.ttf', '', '', 32);
```

After that I have 3 files in my tcpdf fonts directory: aller.php, aller.z and aller.ctg.z
I set font like this:

```
$pdf->SetFont('aller', '', 20, '', true)
```

Unfortunatelly I get dots in my pdf file and error message saying "Cannot extract the embedded font 'AAAAAD+Aller,Bold'. Some characters may not display or print correctly."

I am using windows so i cant use ttf2atm.exe and call php -q makefont.php as suggested in some tutorials.

I found here in SO a question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861260/specific-fonts-in-tcpdf-pdf) but there was no solution.

Does anybody know how to add totally new font to tcpdf pdf file? I want to add Aller font (you can download it from [here](http://pl.fonts2u.com/aller.czcionka?ptext=Konkurencje:&size=&submit=Wy%C5%9Blij) - just klik on 'pobieraj' link.

Help would be appreciated.

Kalreg.

**Problem has been solved - unfortunatelly the font i was trying to embed was corrupted - any other works fine with $pdf->addTTFfont() method.**

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button to add an answer to your question. You should modify your original question only to add additional information.